# Why Spring Boot Backend is not letting me Login due to CORS?

Tags: reactjs, spring, spring-boot

I have a `React`' App front end and I have built using `npm run build`. I'm serving it with `ngnix` and I have a `Spring Boot` back end to handle most of the things rather very important things. Now the code is not coded by me but since I took care of this project I need to fix this even by the fact that I just don't understand why the code is failing me.

So I have `CORS` configuration set up in back end like this:

```
@Bean
    public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.addAllowedOrigin("https://easy-compare.ch"); // domain which is throwing the error
        configuration.addAllowedMethod("OPTIONS");
        configuration.addAllowedMethod("POST");
        configuration.addAllowedMethod("GET");
        configuration.addAllowedHeader("*");
        
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);

        return source;
    }
```

On my development environment it works fine when I add `http://localhost:3000` (the react default link) but in the server it doesn't work that well. This is my `ngnix` configuration and I have spent so many hours I just don't know where to look anymore. On React the URL of login is `/Login` while where the data should be sent is `/login`.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name easy-compare.ch www.easy-compare.ch;

    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name easy-compare.ch www.easy-compare.ch;

    root /var/www/html/easycompare/build;
    index index.html;

    ssl_certificate //ssl config;
    ssl_certificate_key //ssl config;

    location / {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' "https://easy-compare.ch";
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type';
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    location /login {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

Edit: Apparently I did find the issue and its not abut my code in back end or `ngnix` I will post a solution once I have a proper resolving guide.

Comment: Could you check the OPTION request to see the allowed response header? I usually use postman to send this one.

Comment: sorry for late @dnt00 the problem wasn't there but check my answer for a more detailed information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is a bit late than I promised but I can finally write an answer to my problem.

I uploaded the code in the server and I made sure everything was up and running with no problems at all. In the `frontend` code, the `API URL` was still `localhost` because I assumed that the server would make the calls to it's own `localhost` when the functions would fire up and everything was going to be alright.

But I think I overlooked the fact that when I opened the website in the browser; the browser interpreted the `localhost` inside the code as the `localhost` of the `end user`'s PC instead. Which later became the answer of my questions as why the server had some information of my development machine. Since the server has been serving static files, and it was client-side rendered rather than server-side rendered the browser was interpreting the `localhost` as it liked. It's a silly problem which I overlooked at first and later I fixed it by making a new subdomain for my API.